# Show that a function, $f$, is continuous and harmonic.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $u(z,s)$ be a function on $\mathbb{C} × \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous and real valued. Let $u(z,s)$ be harmonic in $z$ for every fixed $s $. Let $f(z) = \int_{-1}^1 u(z,s) ds $.

How do I show that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}$ using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition? Also, how do I show that $f$ is harmonic without taking derivatives?

I think that in order to show that $f$ is harmonic, I need to show that it is continuous and satisfies the mean-value property. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z_0 \in \mathbb C$ then $u$ is uniformly continuous on $\{z:|z-z_0| \leq 1\} \times [-1,1]$. Let $\epsilon >0$ and choose $\delta \in (0,1)$ such that $|u(z,s)-u(z',t)| <\epsilon$ whenever $(z,s),(z't) \in \{z:|z-z_0| \leq 1\} \times [-1,1]$ and $\|(z,s)-(z',t)\|<\delta$. Then $|u(z,s)-u(z_0,s)| <\epsilon$ for all $s \in [-1,1]$ whenever $|z-z_0| <\delta$ and this gives $|f(z)-f(z_0)|\leq \epsilon$. For MVP all you have to do is write down the definition of MVP for $U$ and interchange the integrals. [If you show your effort in this direction I will be glad to help you complete the argument].